# Does sodium borohydride reduce C=N group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

> Q.15 the major product of the following reaction is:
>
> [image]

I have read that $\ce{NaBH4}$ reduces only aldehyde, ketone and acid chlorides. In some cases it may reduce double bonds conjugated with carbonyl groups. So shouldn't the answer here be option **1**?

Comment: Sodium borohydride readily reduces isolated C=N bonds, read up on reductive amination.

Comment: @Waylander Can you provide some reference in the literature?

Comment: try this http://commonorganicchemistry.com/Rxn_Pages/Reductive_Amination/Reductive%20Amination_NaBH4.htm and this  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1001841709003167

Answer (score 2):

Waylander's comments answer the title question as well as I could.  Sodium borohydride, and even modified versions where some of the hydride ligands are replaced by others like $\ce{NaBH3CN}$, can reduce imines.

But, if we have only a limited amount of borohydride we will likely see the carboxyl group primarily reduced, as it has a more polar pi bond and thus it is a more reactive electrophile.  So you may in principle get mostly 1 with limited sodium borohydride, or 4 if you have enough sodium borohydride to attack both the carboxyl and less reactive imine functions.

The carbon-carbon bond here, not conjugated to either electronegatove function, is interactive to borohydride and thus products 2 and 3 are not reached.

Comment: If the question is written exactly as I had uploaded in the question (nowhere excess or anything is mentioned) do you think I should be penalized for writing 1 and not 4 ? Note the question has specifically one correct answer and there are no other details than that I have given in my original question... please reply

Comment: Then either 1or 4 might be formed.  I really can't decide because I do not have ESP and cannot figure whether they mean one or possibly two moles of borohydride reacting.  Always ask precise questions!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question is exactly as written. No other details given. Then what do you think? Please share your opinions, it matters a lot

Comment: The examination commitee has decided that 4 is correct and decided to penalize option 1 . However they are ready to get their answers challenged if proper citations are provided. Please help me if you think that $1$ should not be penalized for the question written with no other specific details. Please sir. (This question is from an undergraduate entrance examination for high school students)

Comment: Then they apparently decided to assume excess borohulydride.  I have no more to say.

Comment: I really would not attempt to reduce an imine in the presence of a carbonyl group. My gut feeling is that the difference in reactivity between the two is not enough that you could differentiate between the two by limiting the amount of borohydride.

Comment: @Waylander okay... if you do not attempt to reduce imine in presence of carbonyl then you would agree that 1 is valid as an answer... wouldn't you?

Comment: No, I think you would get a mixture of 1 and 3 with a limited amount of borohydride. This why 4 is the most sensible answer for the major product.

Comment: How is there 3?  Double bond is n9t conjugated with carbonylgroup.

Comment: Oscar, I think you wrote carboxyl instead of carbonyl in your answer